# Atributo ideal para não ser 'clicável'

Tags: jquery, html, css, css3

Boa tarde. Estou fazendo um botão que tem a função de aumentar a quantidade de produtos no carrinho. Porém, ao clicar muitas vezes nele, o elemento fica como 'colorido' como se fosse uma palavra ou algo do tipo. como nesta imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O ideal para isso não acontecer seria que ele tivesse uma 'propriedade' de background, né? Sendo assim nao seria possível 'clicar' nele. Porém, não quero ter o trabalho de fazer um background para cada coisa que eu não queira esse 'problema'.

vocês sabem algum CSS ou algo do tipo que impeça de acontecer?

Comment: O titulo está meio confuso, não seria: **Atributo ideal para ser clicável?** ou você quis dizer: **Atributo ideal para não ser selecionável?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Podes desligar isso com o [`user-select`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/user-select), que é no fundo a regra que permite ou não o utilizador selecionar conteúdo da página (que é o que acontece aí).

```
.button {
  user-select: none;
}
```

#### Exemplo:

```js
var contador = (function(el) {
  const mostrador = el.querySelector('.mostrador');
  el.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if (!e.target.matches('.button')) return;
    mostrador.innerHTML = Number(mostrador.innerHTML) + Number(e.target.dataset.sinal);
  });
})(document.querySelector('.contador'));
```

```css
.contador {
  border: 2px solid #333;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}

.contador>div {
  display: inline-block;
}

.contador .button:active {
  background-color: #aaf;
}

.mostrador {
  width: 30px;
}

.contador .button {
  border-radius: 15px;
  user-select: none;
  background-color: #aaa;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="contador">
  <div class="button" data-sinal="-1">-</div>
  <div class="mostrador">0</div>
  <div class="button" data-sinal="1">+</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Uma outra forma de evitar isso é através do jQuery abaixo, que também funciona:

```
$(elemento).mousedown(function(){ return false; });
```

> A resposta do [@Sergio](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/229634/8063) realmente é a melhor. Só estou deixando esta
>   como alternativa.

**Só uma observação: no caso da tag BUTTON, ela não é selecionável por padrão. As respostas só serão úteis caso utilize como botão uma DIV, por exemplo.**